# Multiple choice listview not showing all objects

Tags: android, listview

I am following a tutorial about multiple choice listview in android.
When executing the app, the listview shows some items, not all of them. After clicking on the listview, it shows all items.

I want to know where is the reason of that issue.

This is the code for MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    ListView list;
    TextView txt_menu;
    String dipilih;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    Adapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    List<Data> itemList = new ArrayList<Data>();

    // Sesuaikan dengan IP Address PC/LAptop atau ip emulator bawaan android 10.0.2.2
    private static String url = "https://.../test/menu.php";

    public static final String TAG_NAMA = "nama";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        fab     = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        list    = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_menu);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String checkbox = "";
                for (Data hold : adapter.getAllData()) {
                    if (hold.isCheckbox()) {
                        checkbox += "\n" + hold.getMenu();
                    }
                }
                if (!checkbox.isEmpty()) {
                    dipilih = checkbox;
                } else {
                    dipilih = "Anda Belum Memilih Menu.";
                }

                formSubmit(dipilih);
            }
        });

        callVolley();

        adapter = new Adapter(this, (ArrayList<Data>) itemList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                adapter.setCheckBox(position);
            }
        });

    }

    private void formSubmit(String hasil){
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_submit, null);
        dialog.setView(dialogView);
        dialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        dialog.setTitle("Menu Yang Dipilih");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        txt_menu = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txt_menu);

        txt_menu.setText(hasil);

        dialog.setNeutralButton("CLOSE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

    private void callVolley(){
        itemList.clear();
        // menapilkan dialog loading
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        showDialog();

        // membuat request JSON
        JsonArrayRequest jArr = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hideDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                Data item = new Data();

                                item.setMenu(obj.getString(TAG_NAMA));

                                // menambah item ke array
                                itemList.add(item);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        // notifikasi adanya perubahan data pada adapter
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hideDialog();
            }
        });

        // menambah request ke request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jArr);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

And this is the Adapter class:

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context activity;
    private ArrayList<Data> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private View vi;
    private ViewHolder viewHolder;

    public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Data> items) {
        this.activity = context;
        this.data = items;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        vi = view;
        final int pos = position;
        Data items = data.get(pos);

        if(view == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.cb);
            viewHolder.menu = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.nama_menu);
            vi.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            viewHolder.menu.setText(items.getMenu());
        }

        if(items.isCheckbox()){
            viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }

        return vi;
    }

    public ArrayList<Data> getAllData(){
        return data;
    }

    public void setCheckBox(int position){
        Data items = data.get(position);
        items.setCheckbox(!items.isCheckbox());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        TextView menu;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }
}
```

If you need other code parts to detect the problem, please let me know.

EDIT

First launch

[image]

After clicking on the listview

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this bit of your code in your adapter's `getView()` callback:

> ```
> if(view == null) {
>     ...
> }else {
>     ...
>     viewHolder.menu.setText(items.getMenu());
> }
> ```

What's happening here is that you're only caling `setText()` when the item view is recycled by the ListView. The reason everything shows up after you click a checkbox is that the ListView rebinds everything when you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

You should call this method outside of the `if`/`else` statement so that it is executed every time.

```
if(view == null) {
    ...
}else {
    ...
}

viewHolder.menu.setText(items.getMenu());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you are having is coming from the `getView()` method in your `Adapter` class.

Since you are using a ViewHolder to recycle objects you are first checking if the exist first before creating them `if(view == null)`. But, you are only creating them and not assigning the `TextView` objects a `String` value. You only do that once the object has already been created. So, when you click on an item, you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged` causing the list to be updated. Then the values are set in the `TextView.

So try this instead: put the line `viewHolder.menu.setText(items.getMenu());` outside the conditional statement:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    vi = view;
    final int pos = position;
    Data items = data.get(pos);

    if(view == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.cb);
        viewHolder.menu = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.nama_menu);
        vi.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.menu.setText(items.getMenu());

    if(items.isCheckbox()){
        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
    }

    return vi;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, you are right, but  there is another answer with the same explanation, and it was first.

Comment: @mvasco :: Jup, 30 sec! The main thing is you know now why it happened. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

try this once

adapter = new Adapter(this, (ArrayList) itemList);

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            adapter.setCheckBox(position);
        }
    });
     list.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

set adapter at the end